# Android Studio: Graph api image parameter error

Tags: android, image, facebook-graph-api

I have this tinny code that gets the name+pictures of all my friends. The problem is that since I added `parameteres.putString("fields","picture.type(thumbnail).width(50).height(50)")`
Android studio Started returning me the nullPointException. I am not sure why it is. Have I defined the picture type wrong, is it because I put two different parameters. I do not know. But I need both the limit and the picture parameter.
Thanks in advance

```
Bundle parameteres = new Bundle();
    parameteres.putString("limit", Integer.toString(c));
    parameteres.putString("fields","picture.type(thumbnail).width(50).height(50)");
    final GraphRequest requestt =
            new GraphRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    "me/taggable_friends",
                    parameteres,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                            JSONArray arr;
                            MyDBHandler  dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);

                            String name="Just your Teenager :D";

                            int i =0;
                            try {
                                arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                                Product product;
                                name="Somebody that I used to know";
                                JSONObject oneByOne;
                                while(i<(c)) {
                                    oneByOne = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    if(oneByOne==null){
                                        i=c+10;
                                    }
                                    product =
                                            dbHandler.findProductName(oneByOne.opt("name").toString());
                                    JSONObject oneByPic= oneByOne.getJSONObject("picture");
                                    JSONObject url= oneByPic.getJSONObject("data");

                                    if(product==null&&oneByOne!=null){
                                        product =
                                                new Product(oneByOne.opt("name").toString(),-2,2,url.opt("url").toString());

                                        dbHandler.addProduct(product);
                                    }

                                    i++;


                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }


                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), FriendsList.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
            );
    requestt.executeAsync();
```

UPDATE:

It is the declaration that is giving me problems. How do I define picture.type(small) in Android studio?

Comment: What is the variable "c" in Integer.toString(c)? Has it been initialized?

Comment: Yes - it is the total number of my friends (I initialize it before that)

Comment: Where is the null pointer exception being thrown?

Comment: MainActivityFragment$1.onCompleted(MainActivityFragment.java:79)
            at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1360)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Comment: What is at line 79 of the MainActivityFragment?

Comment: arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");

Comment: Step through your code and make sure that obj is not null, and that there is actually a JSONArray in that JSONObject titled "data".

Comment: There is and that is your data, the list (array) of friends.

Comment: +If I remove  parameteres.putString("fields","picture.type(thumbnail).width(50).height(50)");, it works perfectly

Well not perfectly as then my Image won't load from the url

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the GRAPH API does not recognize picture.type(thumbnail).

Changes it to picture.type(small) and it works like a charm